# using awk with column value conditions

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm learning awk from [The AWK Programming Language](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf) and I have a problem with one of the examples.

If I wanted to print $3 if $2 is equal to a value (e.g.`1`), I was using this command which works fine:

```
awk '$2==1 {print $3}' <infile> | more
```

But when I substitute 1 by another searching criteria, (e.g.`findtext`), the command doesn't work:

```
awk '$1== findtext {print $3}' <infile> | more
```

It returns no output and I'm sure that 'findtext' exist on the input file.

I also tried this, but it does not work:

```
awk '$1== "findtext" {print $3}' <infile> | more
```

Here's my test file named 'test' and it has 9 lines and 8 fields, separated by space:

```
1 11 0.959660297 0 0.021231423 -0.0073 -0.0031 MhZisp
2 14 0.180467091 0.800424628 0 0.0566 0.0103 ClNonZ
3 19 0.98089172 0 0 -0.0158 0.0124 MhNonZ
4 15 0.704883227 0.265392781 0.010615711 -0.0087 -0.0092 MhZisp
5 22 0.010615711 0.959660297 0.010615711 0.0476 0.0061 ClNonZ
6 23 0.715498938 0 0.265392781 -0.0013 -0.0309 Unkn
7 26 0.927813163 0 0.053078556 -0.0051 -0.0636 MhZisp
8 44 0.55626327 0.222929936 0.201698514 0.0053 -0.0438 MhZisp
9 31 0.492569002 0.350318471 0.138004246 0.0485 0.0088 ClNonZ
```

Here's what I did and the output:

```
$awk '$8 == "ClNonZ" {print $3}' test 

$ grep ClNonZ test 
2 14 0.180467091 0.800424628 0 0.0566 0.0103 ClNonZ
5 22 0.010615711 0.959660297 0.010615711 0.0476 0.0061 ClNonZ
9 31 0.492569002 0.350318471 0.138004246 0.0485 0.0088 ClNonZ
```

I expect to see this which is the $3 that has "ClNonZ" in their $8.

```
0.180467091 
0.010615711 
0.492569002
```

Don't know why the awk command didn't return anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to quote the string value "findtext", otherwise it's a variable name

Comment: I tried double quotes with "findtext", but it doesn't work.. that's why it bothers me

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. Show us exact inputs, exact code, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If you're looking for a particular string, put quotes around it:

```
awk '$1 == "findtext" {print $3}'
```

Otherwise, awk will assume it's a variable name.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work I don't know why. I double checked with grep and the text was in there. :(

Comment: @user1687130, I think you're going to need to show us some example input and expected output.

Comment: Are you sure your data is space-separated. Might some of those spaces be tabs? Try using awk to echo a single field. Does `awk '{ print $8 }'` give you what you'd expect?

Comment: It might be due to `AWK` implementation (check it with `awk --version`), have a look to my answer, it works in `GAWK` and `MAWK` too.

Comment: This doesn't work when we use double quotes around the awk script. Like `awk "$1 == \"findtext\" {print $3}"`

Comment: Yeah, well that makes sense, since you're probably running that command from a shell, and by using double quotes you're telling the shell not to pass the string directly to awk but to replace $1 and $3 with values first.

Comment: @RobDavis : And what if we want to compare it against any variable ?

Comment: @RobDavis then you would pass a variable to awk, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).  And version is important, this doesn't work on GNU Awk 5.0.1, which I have on my Mac

Answer (score 43):

This method uses regexp, it should work:

```
awk '$2 ~ /findtext/ {print $3}' <infile>
```

Comment: Thanks I was searching a way to use awk to find regex on $NF without using diabolic methods and grep ^^

Answer (score 25):

Depending on the `AWK` implementation are you using `==` is ok or not.

Have you tried `~`?. For example, if you want $1 to be "hello":

```
awk '$1 ~ /^hello$/{ print $3; }' <infile>
```

`^` means $1 start, and `$` is $1 end.

Comment: All awk implementations support both "==" and "~".

Comment: @EdMorton - OS X's `awk` failed to match with `==`, but succeeded with `~`.

Comment: @jww Failed to match what with what? These are equivalent: `$1 == "hello"` and `$1 ~ /^hello$/`. You should never do `$1 ~ "^hello$"` as shown in this answer as it's using a string in a regexp context and so awk has to convert the string to a regexp before using it and that has side-effects (man awk).

Answer (score 9):

This is more readable for me

```
awk '{if ($2 ~ /findtext/) print $3}' <infile>
```

Answer (score 3):

My awk version is 3.1.5.

Yes, the input file is space separated, no tabs.

According to arutaku's answer, here's what I tried that worked:

```
awk '$8 ~ "ClNonZ"{ print $3; }' test  
0.180467091
0.010615711
0.492569002


$ awk '$8 ~ "ClNonZ" { print $3}' test  
0.180467091
0.010615711
0.492569002
```

What didn't work(I don't know why and maybe due to my awk version:),

```
$awk '$8 ~ "^ClNonZ$"{ print $3; }' test
$awk '$8 == "ClNonZ" { print $3 }' test
```

Thank you all for your answers, comments and help!

Comment: This has nothing to do with your awk version. You created your test file on Windows so iwhatever tool you used to do that appended control-Ms to the end of each line so the last field on each line is `ClNonZ<control-M>`, not `ClNonZ` which is why a RE partial match comparison as done with grep or "~" in awk finds it but an equality comparison doesn't.

Comment: Yes, make sense. I tried $dos2unix test and then used "==" to replace "~" and it works. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score -3):

please try this

```
echo $VAR | grep ClNonZ | awk '{print $3}';
```

or

```
echo cat filename | grep ClNonZ | awk '{print $3}';
```

Comment: Sadly this answer does not actually use Awk syntax which the user specifically asked for!