# In Unix, how do I find the 10 most frequent value in column 1 whose values in column 2 == 'blue'?

Tags: unix, awk

I need to find the top 10 frequent numbers in column 1 whose values are 'blue' in column 2. So far I am able to get the top 10 of ALL numbers, but not sure how to add the column 2 constraint.
I have this code so far:

`awk -F ',' '{print $1}' data.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10`

I think I will need to incorporate `'$2=='blue''` somewhere?

Comment: Add an example.

Comment: You are pretty close. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739057 for some ideas.

Comment: Probably just `awk -F ',' '$2=="blue" {print $1}'data.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10`

Comment: I tried awk -F ',' '$2=="blue" {print $1}'data.csv | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10 but it doesn't work

Comment: Come back with something more specific than *it doesn't work*

Comment: It _runs but doesn't output anything_