# look for column having the value as - using awk

Tags: awk

I have a log file in which I have the HTTP status codes I want to skip all the lines with the value as - in column 3.

Since - is a special character I am unable to match that using the == function on awk

```
1_column | 2_column | -
1_column | 2_column | 200
1_column | 2_column | 201
```

I want to skip the below line from being shown

```
1_column | 2_column | -
```

I am trying `awk -F'|' '($3=='-')'` but it doesn't work

Fix - I had to do `awk -F'|' '($3==" - ")'`

Comment: This helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739057/using-awk-with-column-value-conditions?rq=1 I had to do ```awk -F'|' '($3==" - ")'```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
awk -F"|" '$3 !~ /-/ {print $0}' inputfile
```

The `-F"|"` will make | the column separator.
and the entire line (`print $0`) will only appear if the 3rd column does not match "-"